# Gradle - Could not find method mavenRepo() for arguments

Tags: gradle, cascading

I've cloned the [Cascading Pattern](https://github.com/Cascading/pattern) project, [installed](http://www.cerebro.com.au/2013/08/01/java-gradle-install-gradle-in-mac-osx/) [Gradle 2.0](http://www.gradle.org/installation) - run and the commend

```
gradle eclipse --stacktrace
```

and I get the following - **what is the root cause?**

```
J-MacBook-Pro:pattern J$ gradle eclipse --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/J../Documents/.../pattern/etc/s3Upload.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find method mavenRepo() for arguments [{name=monochromeroad, url=http://conjars.org/repo/}] on repository container.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyScript(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$000(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$1.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_lri38cub9qal6ms4fm481qs9d.run(/Users/Julian/Documents/workspace_nonbook/pattern/build.gradle:22)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:470)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:105)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:85)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method mavenRepo() for arguments [{name=monochromeroad, url=http://conjars.org/repo/}] on repository container.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at s3Upload_447b4416rad4bgj0fk7141bgil$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(/Users/Julian/Documents/workspace_nonbook/pattern/etc/s3Upload.gradle:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:59)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.configure(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.configure(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.repositories(DefaultScriptHandler.java:70)
    at s3Upload_447b4416rad4bgj0fk7141bgil$_run_closure1.doCall(/Users/Julian/Documents/workspace_nonbook/pattern/etc/s3Upload.gradle:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:59)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScript.buildscript(DefaultScript.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$buildscript.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at s3Upload_447b4416rad4bgj0fk7141bgil.run(/Users/Julian/Documents/workspace_nonbook/pattern/etc/s3Upload.gradle:24)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`mavenRepo` is deprecated since Gradle 1.8 and it is removed in Gradle 2.0.

This is an incorrect repository in `build.gradle`, line 69:

```
mavenRepo name: 'conjars', url: 'http://conjars.org/repo/'
```

And another one in `/etc/s3Upload.gradle`

```
mavenRepo name: 'monochromeroad', url: 'http://conjars.org/repo/'
```

Replace them with the following repository:

```
maven {
    url 'http://conjars.org/repo/'
}
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer - and it seems nearly there. It's just when I drop it in I get exactly the same error. Could you expand on the file you're modifying (there are several build.gradle files). I tried with both the top level one and the one in build-examples and it didn't work for either.

Comment: I noticed there are multiple `mavenRepo` repositories defined in different gradle files. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

They are using an older version of gradle. I guess they removed the old `mavenRepo` method in version 2.0. [Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.8-rc-1/release-notes.html#support-for-using-ivy-dependencyresolver-implementations) is a reference when they marked it as deprecated.