# Android studio error (17, 0) could not find method maven()

Tags: java, android, maven

Project Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' // google-services plugin
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Module Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23

    }


    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
    compile project(':rateMyApp')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/com-uvxghdmx-ucuwreks167365.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Getting Error

```
Error:(17, 0) Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_2rpdxydj6arlyq4m2v87kde3g$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3@70ca8e63] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Please Help Me...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382752/gradle-could-not-find-method-mavenrepo-for-arguments

Comment: John Thank You, this is same error?

Comment: You can try and see

Comment: John, same error this is doesnt work... :(

Answer (score 2):

You can work this one around like by adding the mavenCentral() to the repositories, then add the code to the repositories below the mavenCentral() line, and then resync:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

this should remove the conflict with the sync.